# Problem with FILTER Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, spreadsheet

I'm trying to understand the FILTER Function in Google Sheets, so I copy a example on the Google web:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en

I do it in my sheet, but I receive a ERROR and I do not understand what is which I'm doing badly. Can someone help me?

Here is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NvYTlJnJ_YcvpTbCnAa6VK1htRf8jcCk3Z4tWQbdfX4/edit?usp=sharing

I did not found more info online so I need help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your locale probably requires the use of semicolons as argument separator(s). So See if this works:

```
=FILTER(A2:C6; ISBLANK(C2:C6))
```